# I need help to make a vertical resize bar

Tags: html, css

My question is simple, I have three divs, which are visually horizontal, but I would like to leave them as same aspect, but vertically. I'm a beginner, I researched and tried to do it myself, but I could not. Follow the code:

```css
.note-icon-bar {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
}
```

```html
<div class="note-statusbar">  
  <div class="note-resizebar">    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to leave these three small bars vertically for me to make a resize bar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can simplify your code and use one div (2 border + 1 linear-gradient) then adjust the needed values:

```css
.note-icon-bar-v {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  height: 20px;
  width: 7px;
  margin: 1px auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-left: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) 2px 0/1px 100% no-repeat;
}
.note-icon-bar-h {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 7px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  background: linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) 0 2px/100% 1px  no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="note-icon-bar-v"></div>
<div class="note-icon-bar-h"></div>
```

Comment: Temani tested its solution in Google Chrome, but apparently the linear-gradient did not work. Was there any alternative?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira are you sure you copied the exact code ? did you made any changes to it ?  as i work mainly with chrome and it works fine

Comment: @RafaelOliveira also you said it's was exactly what you want which means it's working here ?

Comment: At first it started to work in chrome. I am using the Brackets editor and when I was running the chrome for it, it was not working the linear gradient.
Please see my code if you can. If you find any improvement, tell me.

My code is this:
[This Code!](http://jsfiddle.net/YZX6B/1873/)

Comment: @RafaelOliveira i see the vertical bars in your code. you don't see them ?

Comment: I did two tests, one I opened the html file through Chrome directly, and it usually appeared the vertical bars.
In another test I opened Chrome with the Brackets editor functionality and it appeared like this:

[Link](https://ibb.co/nrHjiH)

Comment: @RafaelOliveira ok i update the code, maybe you have `box-sizing:border-box;` defined somewhere .. try with this one

Answer (score 2):

That is what you want? Mainly it is using **float**

```css
.note-resizebar { 
  position: relative; 
  clear: both;
}
.note-resizebar .note-icon-bar {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 1px 2px;
    border-top: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
    
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="note-statusbar">  
  <div class="note-resizebar">    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can apply display inline-block.

```
.note-resizebar{
 display:block;
}
.note-icon-bar {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 1px auto;
    border: 1px solid #red;
   display: inline-block;
}

<div class="note-statusbar">  
  <div class="note-resizebar">    
    <div class="note-icon-bar">1</div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar">2</div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar">3</div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, you need to set the parent on flex and adapt the children :

```css
.note-resizebar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.note-icon-bar {
    height: 20px;
    width: 0px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    border-right: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
}
```

```html
<div class="note-statusbar">  
  <div class="note-resizebar">    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>    
    <div class="note-icon-bar"></div>  
  </div>
</div>
```